# Arithmetic for loop through arrays of pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have two arrays of pointers. I need to do simple arithmetic with them while going in loop

```
 float **x_points, **y_points;

x_points = malloc(sizeof(float*) * n);
y_points = malloc(sizeof(float*) * n);

for( i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("x");
    printf("%i",i);
    printf(" : ");
    x_points[i] = malloc( n * sizeof ( float ) );
    scanf("%f",x_points[i]);

    printf("y");
    printf("%i",i);
    printf(" : ");
    y_points[i] = malloc( n * sizeof ( float ) );
    scanf("%f",y_points[i]);
}

x_points[n] = NULL;
y_points[n] = NULL;
```

And here I have problems:

```
int k;

for(k=0; k < i; k++) {
    R += *x_points[k] * *y_points[k+1] - *x_points[k+1] * *y_points[k];
}
```

Couldn't you tell me why does this code shows me a window says that the system got a signal and that's why stopped the program? THank you, I will appreciate it!

Comment: This code has multiple problems, not just with that loop (the placement of which remains a mystery because you haven't posted an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're allocating n pointers:

```
x_points = malloc(sizeof(float*) * n);
y_points = malloc(sizeof(float*) * n);
```

but here you're accessing past of the memory you've allocated:

```
x_points[n] = NULL;
y_points[n] = NULL;
```

Since `C` is `0-based` for `indices`, you can only go from `0` to `n-1`.

So you either need to allocate `n+1`, or to put your `null` at `n-1`

Edit: also what hmjd said. I didn't catch it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason could be that you are accessing un-allocated memory location.
Change

```
for(k=0; k < i; k++)
```

to

```
for(k=0; k < i - 1; k++)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x_points[n] = NULL;
y_points[n] = NULL;
```

is also invalid as your assigning the value outside the memory allocated to it.

change the malloc call a bit if wanna still achieve this

`malloc( n+1 * sizeof ( float ) )`